# SMTP mail errors

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I am developing a C# application to send mail using the SMTP server of our company mail. The following is the code.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("10.203.195.48");

mail.From = new MailAddress("");
mail.To.Add("");
mail.Subject = "filename";
mail.Body = "Report";

SmtpServer.Host = "ip address fo smtp mail server.";
SmtpServer.Port = 25;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

But I get this error:

> mailbox unavailable.unable to relay.The system doesn't have internet connection.

Comment: Are you really passing in blank values for `mail.To.Add` and `System.Net.NetworkCredential`?  The error message(s?) are pretty self-explanatory.  `Unable to relay` - by default most corporate mail servers turn off relaying so they can't be used for sending out spam, for example.

Comment: Take a look at this thread - [`Error: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was 5.7.1 Unable to relay for (email)`](http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/error-mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1t-315971.html)

Answer (score 1):

The following code is for [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) using port 587. You just change your port and SMTP.

Add Namespace

```
using system.net
MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("emailid");
MyMailMessage.To.Add("To");
MyMailMessage.Subject = "Feedback Form";
MyMailMessage.Body = "This is the test message";
MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
SMTPServer.Port = 587;
SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username","password");
SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;

try
{
    SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.message("error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From *[Error: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was 5.7.1 Unable to relay for (email)](http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/error-mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1t-315971.html)*:

> Generally it occurs when you have a mail server (e.g. mailserver.com) from one domain, and the addresses are from other domains. Either the From or the To address need to belong to the domain (myname@mailserver.com or yourname@mailserver.com). If neither of the addresses belong to a domain that the mail server 'owns', then you are relaying, which is a spam technique and is generally not allowed nowadays."

See also blog post *[Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay sendername](http://ashrafur.wordpress.com/2008/01/17/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-571-unable-to-relay-sendername/)*.